# How to host and embed a video, and stop it from being downloaded?

Tags: video, embed

I'd like to host a video, even on another platform, and embed the video on a web page, but protect it as much as possible from being downloaded. Could you guys give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You basically can't stop it being downloaded - the player needs to receive it to play it and there are many ways to capture a video once it is downloaded.

The usual defence is to encrypt it so that it is not usable when downloaded unless you have the key. You need a secure way to share the key with authorised users - this is essentially what a DRM system does.

If you are prepared to accept a less secure solution, but one which will probably deter casual copying and may be suitable for low value content, then clearly or HLS AES encryption may meet your needs:

- List item

There is an example of cleasrkey DRM provided with the open source Shakla web player: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. FYI, this is short, but high value content